# why doesn't this work in XCode debug window "po [myNsDateComponent weekday]"

Tags: iphone, xcode, gdb, xcode4

why doesn't this work in XCode debug window "po [myNsDateComponent weekday]" ?

Specific example:

```
(gdb) po weEndDayTime
<NSDateComponents: 0x4f241d0>

(gdb) po [weEndDayTime weekday]
0x2 does not appear to point to a valid object.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-weekday` method of `NSDateComponents` returns an `int`. But `po` doesn't work with primitive value types, only pointer types.

In this case, it's converting the integer output of that method, `0x2`, to a pointer, and looking for an object with the pointer address of `0x2`. It can't find anything, so it gives that message.

Use `p` instead, with the appropriate typecast if necessary:

```
(gdb) p (int) [weEndDayTime weekday]
$1 = 2
```

Comment: actually when I try this I get - "Unable to call function "objc_msgSend" at 0x11ed08c: no return type information available.
To call this function anyway, you can cast the return type explicitly (e.g. 'print (float) fabs (3.0)')"  ?

Comment: Then try casting it as it tells you?